# multiple expressions after identifer error

Tags: scheme

Here is the code:

```
(define path (lambda lst start end)
  (let ((nodes (car lst))
        (edges (cdr lst)))))
```

Why is this causing an error?

Answer (score 2):

You misused `lambda` keyword, and function body isn't complete.

```
(define path (lambda (lst start end)
      (let ((nodes (car lst))
            (edges (cdr lst)))
        ; here should be expression, i think with lst, nodes and edges

)))
```

Comment: how would i simply say nodes = car lst.

Comment: That's what you did say; within the body of the `let` (where paul put the comment), `nodes` will be bound to the result of the expression `(car lst)`. If you want `path` to return that, you need to evaluate it.

Answer (score 0):

Note: when you say "Can anyone help me with this error", please include what error message you're seeing.  Your whole program can't be an error in itself.  But it can *contain* errors, and when you try running it, it can produce error messages.

I'm assuming you saw error messages.  Include those too, next time.  Also tell us what you expected to see.  Did you expect to get the error you're seeing?

The reason why you should include the actual error message is because the problem you're seeing may not even have anything to do with what you think the problem is.  In that case, the error message allows us to make sure we're on the right track in solving your problem.

---

Looking at your program, I think it's syntactically incomplete.  A [`let`](http://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-7.html#%_idx_124) needs to have at least a `body`, or else it's ungrammatical according to the language's rules.  There's no body present in:

```
 (let ((nodes (car lst))
       (edges (cdr lst)))
    )
```

(An analogous error message in a language like C would occur if you try to use the `if` statement but not include a test.)

At the very least, you can include some kind of placeholder until you figure out what you really need to put in there.  For example:

```
 (let ((nodes (car lst))
       (edges (cdr lst)))
   "fixme")
```

should at least make the program a syntactically acceptable one.  Though it won't do anything too useful yet.